# Add mapnik library to eclipseC++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt, vcpkg, mapnik

I downloaded and built mapnik library with vcpkg after that I tried add the mapnik to eclipse.For GCC C++ compiler Include :"/home/ubuntuc/vcpkg/packages/mapnik_x64-linux/include" and for GCC C++ linker :"/home/ubuntuc/vcpkg/packages/mapnik_x64-linux/lib" added.When ı tried to build its gave me these:

```
"Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
recipe for target 'src/hello.o' failed  subdir.mk   /hello/Debug/src    line 18 C/C++ Problem,
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [src/hello.o] Error 1 hello           C/C++ Problem,
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
recipe for target 'hello' failed    makefile    /hello/Debug    line 58 C/C++ Problem,
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

fatal error: boost/operators.hpp: there is no such a file or directory hello        line 33, external location: /home/ubuntuc/vcpkg/packages/mapnik_x64-linux/include/mapnik/color.hpp  C/C++ Problem.
```

Did I add the library wrong or there is a problem in build of library.

Comment: Looks like `mapnik` requires `boost`. Do you have the `boost` library  installed on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

As @zkoza said, mapnik requires boost. If you installed mapnik with vcpkg you would need to add all of mapnik dependencies, too.
As those are quite a few, I recommend using either pkgconfig oder cmake to manage them.